# Dynamic views in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

If I have a view definition, say in xml, can I dynamically build a flutter view with child widgets (recursively) determined at runtime (using an xml element)?

Answer (score 1):

Widgets are by definition a layout determined at runtime. Therefore nothing really prevents you from doing it.

There's to my knowledge no library doing it though. But you can make your own using an xml parser.

You may also want to look at dart code generations with [source_gen](https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen) to not have to include the xml file in your assets; as you'd generate a widget from your xml during development.